# how to prevent checking a checkbox using query

Tags: jquery

I've a group of check boxes in my page and I want to prevent checking a check box from user if he already checked two boxes. Somehow I solved my problem but I'm not satisfied with my current solution because I don't think its the proper way to do the same.  So I'm here for a better option,my current code is given below

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chkTest" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkTest" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkTest" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkTest" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkTest" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkTest" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkTest" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkTest" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkTest" />
```

**Script**

```
    $(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $(".chkTest").change(function () {

            if ($(".chkTest").is(":checked")) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count > 2) {
                $(this).attr("checked", false);
                alert("only two");
            }

        });
    });
```

Any thoughts???

Comment: You want the property, *not* the attribute, so `this.checked = false`.

Comment: @Krishna is right, the "proper" way to handle this is to disable the other checkboxes, so the user knows they can't check anymore before they even try.

Comment: guys I know about this.cheked=false what about the first segment of my code using count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would disable all unchecked boxes when you have 2 options picked, and enable all of them when you have zero or one checked.

```
$(".chkTest").change(function () {
    if ($(".chkTest:checked").length < 2) {
        $(".chkTest").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
       $(".chkTest:not(:checked)").prop("disabled", true); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$(".chkTest").change(function () {
    if ($(".chkTest:checked").length > 2) {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Jc9qn/)**

Comment: No need to use `prop()`, just use `this.checked = false`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - true, I was just sticking with all JQ. Six of one, half dozen of another.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var $checks = $(".chkTest").change(function () {
        if ($checks.filter(':checked').length > 2) {
            this.checked = false;
            alert("only two");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KvUm4/)

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
 $(function () {
    var count  = $(".chkTest:checkbox:checked").length;

    $(".chkTest").click(function (e) {
        if (count > 2) {
            alert("only two");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```